# "Learning curve" behavior comparison

Tags: machine-learning

I am comparing two learning algorithms using the log learning rate. I plot training data size vs. Mean Absolute Error (MAE). In the figure below, you can see method 1 shown with black line and method 2 with blue line.

[image]

One interpretation is that method 2 works better when the training data size is lower and vise versa.

I remembered something in the following line but couldn't find it looking it up online: Is it OK for the logarithmic learning curve to asymptote to an error? Or does it show a problem with the method.

I appreciate if someone can elaborate on this or let me know if there is no such thing. Thanks!

---

EDITS:

This image confirms what I remembered is correct. Link: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.04259.pdf

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, this looks like normal behaviour. It could happen if, for example:

- method 1 (black line) is a more complicated model with a large number of trainable parameters
- method 2 (blue line) is a simpler model with only a few trainable parameters.

In that case, for *small* sample sizes:

- method 1 has only a few data points for a lot of parameters and overfits on the training data, leading to a high validation loss (I assume that's what you have plotted on the $y$ axis?)
- method 2 has fewer parameters, so does not overfit. The validation loss is lower than for method 1.

However, for *large* sample sizes:

- method 1, being a more complicated model, can fit the data better. Since there are more data points, there is less overfitting and the validation loss keeps decreasing.
- method 2 has only a few parameters, which do not change much upon adding more data. Since the model is simple, it cannot find a good "fit" and the validation loss bottoms out.

There's a great paper on this exact topic: *Classifier design for computer-aided diagnosis: Effects of finite sample size on the mean performance of classical and neural network classifiers* by Chan and Sahiner in Medical Physics, 1999. You can find a copy [here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Heang_Ping_Chan/publication/292795264_Classifier_design_and_sample_size_effects_for_computer-aided_diagnosis/links/5bf188224585150b2bc01cd1/Classifier-design-and-sample-size-effects-for-computer-aided-diagnosis.pdf). It provides a nice explanation, including diagrams, for some toy problems where this occurs.

Here's a picture from that paper that I modified. The $A_z$ is like the accuracy, so the higher the accuracy, the lower the loss. It shows $A_z$ against inverse sample size. The L is a linear model and Q a quadratic one. For small sample sizes, the quadratic model overfits and has a lower validation accuracy. But, for high sample sizes, it can fit the data better than the linear one and has a higher accuracy.

[image: error_sample_size]

I'd recommend reading the paper as it explains what is happening better than I can.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, A. P. H.! I agree with the analogy. I have a concern, though. With the new plot that I included in my problem, wouldn't one conclude that this is a poor model?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by a "poor" model. For some problems, no model exists for which the error decreases to 0 as the sample size tends to infinity. In the paper I linked, they discuss classifying points drawn from one of 2 normal distributions with the same covariance. For this problem, the _optimal_ classifier is a linear classifier, but this model will still have some error if the normal distributions have a similar mean. Hence, I think it's a bit silly to say that only models whose error tends to 0 are "good" -- this means that, sometimes, no "good" models exist!